# Batch File to read 'N' characters from a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, character

I have searched this across the net and found many codes for retrieving the entire line from a text or replacing the text with another but not for what i was looking for.

Using the For loop with the tokens would return on the set (word) separated with spaces.

I want to pull only a few characters from the line.

Eg: `12345qwerty67890`

If this on in a text file i want to pull only '12345' and assign it to a variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is your criteria for splitting here

Comment: He wants to extract a certain predetermined number of characters.

Comment: I added the "windows" tag, because that's what you probably mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `HELP SET` and try the following to get you started

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set chars=!line:~0,5!
  echo !chars! --- !line!
)
```

Comment: Hi PA, I have tried this but the %chars% doesn't return anything. %line% does return the whole string, i am guessing chars=!line:~0,5! line has a problem ?

Comment: it just gives me 'Echo is on'

Comment: C:\>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

C:\>for /F "tokens= 1" %a in (1.txt) do (set line=%a set chars=~0,3  )

C:\>(set line=12345BLRPN0W01085 set chars=~0,3  )

C:\>ECHO
ECHO is on.

C:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: This is the code it tried...setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens= 1" %%a in (1.txt) do (set line=%%a set chars=%line:~0,3% )


ECHO %chars%

Comment: It worked i put chars=!line:~0,5! in the next line :) ... Thanks !!

Comment: PA's code works for me. So now we need to find out what's different between your setup and our setups. I am using Windows XP Professional, and my HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Enable Extensions value is 0x01. --Oh, OK, if it worked for you, then scratch this.

Comment: another question, instead of the first 5 characters if i want the middle characters ? like character 6th to the 10th character

Answer (score 2):

At the command prompt, do `help set`. There you will find more information about the `set` command than you would ever want to know. The part you are interested in says:

```
May also specify substrings for an expansion.

    %PATH:~10,5%

would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
remainder of the variable value.  If either number (offset or length) is
negative, then the number used is the length of the environment variable
value added to the offset or length specified.
```

Of course, in order to use that kind of stuff with the `for` loop variable, you need to first get acquainted with the very peculiar way in which variables are expanded in Windows NT batch files. Let me know if you have problems with that, and I can add more information.

Comment: Thanks mike, ill try this out and let you know

Comment: Well, @PA. beat me to it by 44 seconds.

Comment: And he provided a full example taking care of the peculiarities that I mentioned about variable expansion.  So, he deserves the credit.

Comment: you too, for taking the time to retag the post, and giving me the chance to beat you :)