# Batch file to remove first 10 chars from txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to remove the first 10 characters from multiple lines inside a text file using a batch script, then output the results to a new file. I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591566/batch-file-to-read-n-characters-from-a-text-file) and it got me pointed in the right direction but the final output isn't working.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\System32\prnport.vbs -l > c:\IPPorts.txt
type c:\IPPorts.txt | findstr IP_ > c:\IPPorts2.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\IPPorts2.txt) do (set line=%%a set chars=!line:~10! > c:\IPPorts3.txt)
for /f "delims=" %%x in (c:\IPPorts3.txt) do CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\System32\prnport.vbs -d -r %%x
```

The 2nd line exports a list of printer ports to a file named IPPorts.txt. The 3rd finds the lines with "IP_" in them and exports to IPPorts2.txt. The 4th line is supposed to remove unneeded text (which it isn't doing) and export to IPPorts3.txt. And the last line will take the results from IPPorts3.txt and then delete those ports.

IPPorts.txt is as follows:

```
Server name 
Port name IP_172.20.51.11
Host address 172.20.51.11
Protocol RAW
Port number 9100
SNMP Disabled
```

These lines are repeated for every port, of which there are several. Since I only need the line containing the port name, IPPorts2.txt looks like this:

```
Port name IP_172.20.51.11
Port name IP_172.20.52.58
Port name IP_172.20.53.16
Port name IP_172.20.54.19
Port name IP_172.20.55.15-1
Port name IP_172.20.55.15
Port name IP_172.20.55.11
```

Where I'm having trouble is removing the "Port name " portion of the lines (the first 10 characters). I want the output to read on each line as "IP_X.X.X.X". The problem is the 3rd file is always empty.

Where am I going wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
This is further down under Endoro's answer, but I thought it might be nice to post the answer here. Here's what I changed the 4th line to:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%c in ('type c:\IPPorts2.txt') do (
 set LINE=%%c
 >> c:\IPPorts3.txt echo !LINE:~10!
 )
```

This has corrected my problems. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
(for /f "tokens=3" %%i in (IPPorts2.txt) do @echo %%i)>IPPorts3.txt
```

Comment: This actually increased the output...
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo IP_172.20.55.15 
IP_172.20.55.15

Comment: Is it legal to answer your own question? Here's what I just tried and it worked.

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%c in ('type c:\IPPorts2.txt') do (
     set LINE=%%c
     >> c:\IPPorts3.txt echo !LINE:~10!
    )

Comment: 1) what do you mean with "increased the output"?? 2) yes, you can answer to your own question.

Comment: Yes Josh, it's encouraged to answer your own question if you found an answer after asking.  Make it an answer, and accept it.  It will help the next person with a similar question.

Comment: @NateHekman - It won't let me answer my own question due to my reputation.

Comment: I'm interrsted in what's going wrong. Please tell me, what do you mean with `increased the output` ??

Comment: @Endoro - I meant that instead of the contents of the file being just _"IP_X.X.X.X"_, it looked like this for every line:
_C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo IP_X.X.X.X IP_X.X.X.X_

Comment: @Josh - I tried it with the content, that you posted. OK, please copy your content from SO back in a file (with `notepad`) and try it again.

Comment: @Josh: Apparently you need to suppress the output of command lines. Just put the `@ECHO OFF` command somewhere at the beginning of your script. However, you can avoid dealing with output files completely, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Script to get directory name out of DIR command output :

...
20/09/2014  01:23    [DIR]          some1
21/09/2014  02:34    [DIR]          some2
22/09/2014  03:45    [DIR]          some3
23/09/2014  11:22    [DIR]          some4
...
We want it to be:
some1
some2
some3
some4
...

Code :

```
@FOR /f "tokens=4" %%D IN (i:\test.txt) DO @( echo %%D ) >> result.txt
```

In your case tokens=3, not perfect but does the job with few lines manually edited in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
(For /f "tokens=3delims= " %%i in (ipports2.txt) do echo %%i) >ipports3.txt
```

should do it for you.

The paretheses are important - ensure that the file is created anew. If omitted, will only generate the last line.

Simply uses the delimiter [space] to tokenise the string on each line into token1=`Port`, token2=`Name` and sets %%i to each token3 in turn.

Comment: This actually increased the output... C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo IP_172.20.55.15 IP_172.20.55.15

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't really a different solution but merely a suggestion to simplify your script by reducing the number of output files.

In fact, it is possible to exclude all of them from the script, unless you need to keep them for history.

Basically, the idea is first to apply `FINDSTR` directly to the output of `prnport.vbs`:

```
CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\System32\prnport.vbs -l | FINDSTR "IP_"
```

then apply a loop directly to the output of `FINDSTR` (note the single quotation marks around the piped command line, as well as the escaped `|`):

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN (
  'CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\System32\prnport.vbs -l ^| FINDSTR "IP_"'
) DO …
```

and call `prnport.vbs` with another set of arguments in that same loop:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN (
  'CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\System32\prnport.vbs -l ^| FINDSTR "IP_"'
) DO (
  CSCRIPT /nologo %windir%\System32\prnport.vbs -d -r %%A
)
```

The `tokens` option of a `FOR /F` loop specifies which token (or field) to take based on a specific delimiter or set of delimiters. The default set of delimiters is a space, a comma, a tab. Your `Port name IP_whatever` lines conveniently consist of exactly three tokens and the third one is what you are after, hence `"tokens=3"` in the options.

So, as you can see, no output files, the necessary value is extracted and passed to the target command *in the same iteration*.

Comment: Andriy, I'll definitely give this a try. I didn't like the output files, but it did help figure out what text I needed to be looking for and removing. Now that I know, I'll apply this and see what happens. Thanks for sharing!